# How do i disable launchpad animation on mac?

Tags: imac, launchpad

I want to disable the animation when I open Launchpad on a Mac.

Is there any way?[image]

I somehow lag out when using Launchpad, is there any fix to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Disable Launchpad Open Animation

```
defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-show-duration -float 0
```

#### Disable Launchpad Close Animation

```
defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-hide-duration -float 0
```

#### Disable Launchpad Scrolling Animation

```
defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-page-duration -float 0
```

Comment: I pasted the code into terminal and it works a lot! Thanks.

Comment: Disable Launchpad Scrolling Animation doesn't work anymore?

Comment: Does anyone know how to disable the page scrolling animation?

Comment: I found the solution! After you execute the last command, restart launchpad from terminal by doing "killall Dock", and everything will work.